# How do current transformers work?

Tags: current, transformer, current-transformer

I'm interested in generating reasonably high amounts of current (50-100 amps), and I was wondering how to go about making that much current without insane amounts of voltage. I've read about current transformers, but am unsure about their operation

Comment: How much voltage it takes to produce 100 A depends entirely what kind of load you're trying to drive the 100 A into.

Comment: Iout = In*Vin/Vout  limited by VA capacity of .... CT's per se are a special application for current sensing, not current welding

Comment: A current transformer is a measurement device - it is placed on a wire carrying the current you want to measure, and the output of the current transformer is conected to your meter or other measuring device.

Comment: What is you voltage? Current Transformers are used for measuring current flow in cables...not for producing current flow. High current applications such a roll welding, spot welding and rod welding are based on Voltage transformers at various voltage levels and high currents....but since we don't know what you are trying to do it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: A soldering gun is an example of your spec that needs amplification

Comment: I was looking to experiment with arcs, specifically for metalworking, and I think now these comments have cleared some things up. So its true that it'ts just the voltage and load that determines the current?

Comment: @EmmettP Essentially, yes. \$V = IR\$

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an AC arc welding transformer. Sometimes called a buzzbox transformer, these welding transformers convert 240V to about 24V open-circuit. The one I own is rated for 270A at a 15% duty cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Current transformers consist of:

- A primary, which has few if any turns. Often, it's just a straight piece of wire. The primary carries a large alternating current.
- A ring of high permeability material around the primary, or with the primary turns on it.  This is the core.
- A secondary wound onto the core. Usually wound like a toroidal transformer.
- The secondary is connected to something with a low impedance, often an ammeter.

The current in the secondary is much smaller, and almost proportional to, the current in the primary.  Thus it is a good way of measuring a large current in the primary.  Additional benefits are the minimal electrical disturbance to the primary, and the fact they can be made of two semicircular cores and clipped onto a wire.

All in all, they are a good tool for measuring large currents, but I don't see any way of using them to generate large currents. If you want a >100A current, but at low-ish voltage, why not use one or more car batteries? One decent car battery should provide 100A at 11.5V or so, and you can add more in series for higher voltages, or parallel for longer run times.

Answer (score 1):

A transformer is an electric machine that can change the voltage and current. It works like this: [image: Transformer]

*Source: [SamaMotor](https://samamotor.ir/blog/108-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B3%D9%81%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B1-%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%88-%DA%86%DA%AF%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D9%85%DB%8C%DA%A9%D9%86%D8%AF.html).*

It works on the principle that a changing magnetic field induces a voltage difference in a conductor, generating current (this is also how spinning generators work). This is why it only works with AC; DC would produce a constant magnetic field and not induce current, unless one constantly increases the current which would need perpetually increasing amounts of energy.

From the image, you can see that there are 2 coils of wire wrapped around a magnetic core, which forms 2 inductors, which is how magnetic fields are generated. Primary current from the AC source goes to its inductor and generates a magnetic field, which induces a voltage in the secondary inductor (and obviously a current). In this way the secondary circuit can have current flow.

Many sources say that the secondary : primary voltage ratio depends on the secondary : primary turn ratio; this is true, but incomplete. Assuming all else equal, a secondary coil with more turns will indeed produce a higher voltage, and one with less turns will produce a lower voltage.

The reason this happens is because of the inductance of the coils. An inductor's energy is

J = 1/2 * H * A^2

where J is energy in joules, H is inductance in henrys, and A is current in amps. One can see that voltage doesn't matter for energy storage; however, higher voltage (assuming same current) will build the magnetic field sooner (because it's delivering more power). Higher inductance means proportionally more energy stored, and to build the magnetic field up in the same time, one needs proportionally higher voltage.

Now in the transformer, the changing magnetic field induces a voltage difference in the secondary inductor - this means current is flowing through the inductor, and clearly there must be energy in it. Remember that energy is the same in both because of conservation of energy and power. Since both inductors have current flowing in the same timespan, this means that the higher inductance one must have a higher voltage, and a lower current to conserve energy.

So, certainly more secondary turns means higher voltage. But this is because more turns causes more inductance. You can increase the output voltage by increasing the secondary inductance in any way - a different core, more turns, etc. The reverse works too - you can decrease the output voltage by decreasing the inductance of the secondary coil. This will cause a higher current to conserve power.

Comment: Agniva Chaudhuri - Hi, Thanks for trying add a reference to that image, as explained in [this site rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). However the added link should be to the **original source webpage** of that image, not just adding a link to the image which is already in your answer. If you have any questions about this, you can leave me a comment here. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I should explain - I got the image from Imgur after netsearching "transformer electricity", which is why I had put the Imgur link. After your comment, I reverse image netsearched with Google, and using the custom date filter, the earliest source I found was a webpage in Persian from 1999; that is what is currently cited. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want AC current then it's fairly trivial to make one of these but you have to know what you are doing in terms of safety and insulation: -

[image]

It's a regular AC power transformer that has a custom one or two-turn copper-plate secondary winding. So, if primary turns are (say) 500 and input voltage is 230V AC, the output voltage will be about 0.5 to 1 volts RMS and capable of a lot of current (limited by the VA rating).

If VA rating is 100 then you could, with a single secondary turn, extract about 200 amps.

If you want DC current in the hundreds of amps then I'd use an arrangement of batteries and a charger for when the energy is starting to deplete.

A CT is a measurement device and cannot be reliably used to generate high values of AC current.

Comment: Thanks! I might try that arrangement if I get my hands on any large transformers

Comment: It doesn't need to be large. A 30 VA transformer might have 1000 primary turns and therefore produce an output voltage of 0.23V RMS from 230 V AC. This means you can take 30/0.23 amps = 130 amps from the secondary. Of course, if you explained what you were trying to do there may be a better solution. If you do leave an explanation, can you add it as an edit section to the question.

Comment: So in essence, more windings on the secondary steps up voltage at the expense of current, and more windings on the primary steps up current at the expense of voltage

Answer (score 0):

> I'm interested in generating reasonably high amounts of current (50-100 amps), and I was wondering how to go about making that much current without insane amounts of voltage. I've read about current transformers, but am unsure about their operation

You can get high current without insane amounts of voltage by using a low resistance load.

What is critical is the voltage you need to develop into the load. I built a 100 A source for testing electricity meters some while ago. As I only needed 5 V or so to energise a dozen meters in series, I bought a 600 VA toroidal transformer. I unwound the secondary, and then wound a new secondary of a few turns of 40 mm2 single core cable.